# How to flush changes in PlayerSettings inside Editor

Tags: unity, c#, editors

I have a script which works only in the Editor. The script makes changes inside PlayerSettings. However, the changes made are flushed to the hard drive just after something in Unity is saved for example any scene.

We have a script which increments the build version. The described issue sometimes leads to the wrong version committed to Git as the changes a flushed to the disk later.

How can I flush the changes of PlayerSettings from the code?

Comment: I'm not able to test just now, but have you had any luck with `AssetDatabase.SaveAssets` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DMGregory

`AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();`

Will flush the changes to disk.

Comment: Please don't forget to come back in a couple of days to mark this answer as accepted :)